# CSS3 gradient rendering issues from transparent to white

Tags: css, gradient

I am having issues with cross browser rendering of CSS3 gradients. This is happening when I am trying to create a gradient from transparent colour to white.

The file I am using to test with is:
http://f.cl.ly/items/0E2C062x3O161b09261i/test.html

CSS used is:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
```

Rending looks like what I want in Safari 6 (mac): 
[image: Safari 6 Mac OS 10.8]

Chrome rendering fades to gray colour before it fades to white (Firefox renders this way also on mac os):
[image: Chrome 21 Mac OS 10.8]

Any ideas or suggestions on why this odd rendering might be?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

I've encountered this as well. I'm not sure why it happens, but here's what I've used in my own projects as a workaround:

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.001) 0%, #fff 5%, #fff 100%);
```

Instead of giving Chrome a "transparent" value, give it something very, very close to transparent.

Edit: I forgot to post a link to my own [version](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/73603348/gradient.html), which renders as expected in Chrome 21 (Windows 7).

Comment: I had this issue in which Safari was rendering `transparent` differently than every other browser I checked. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I believe you can actually use `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)` to get true transparency - it works for me anyway :)

Comment: This is an old post. Browsers have since fixed their transparency-related bugs, and now this works: https://codepen.io/peiche/pen/mMKaLP

Comment: Unfortunately, 'transparent' still doesn't work in Safari, not even in Safari TP. This is because 'transparent' is treated as 'transparent black'; specifying an actual color with alpha of 0 works.

Comment: @Kovensky I managed to fix Safari issue using rgba with 0 alpha for same color it transits to. E.g. in case you want gradient from transparent to lime (`rgb(0, 255, 0)`), use this:
`background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 255, 0, 0), lime)`
Hope this can help.
Edit: just noticed you are talking about same fix, sorry :)

Comment: Works also with `rgba(255,255,255,0)`!

Answer (score 31):

The CSS I pasted in here was wrong, I was editing the wrong file DOH!

### Original CSS not working

```
background-image: linear-gradient(top, transparent 0%, #fff 5%, #fff 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0%, #fff 5%, #fff 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0%, #fff 5%, #fff 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0%, #fff 5%, #fff 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0%, #fff 5%, #fff 100%);
```

### CSS that fixed the problem

```
background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, #fff 5%, #fff 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, #fff 5%, #fff 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, #fff 5%, #fff 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, #fff 5%, #fff 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, #fff 5%, #fff 100%);
```

Problem being transparent isn't a colour, it is black with 0 alpha, setting to specifically white with 0 alpha fixes the issue. (thanks @carisenda)

This still points on inconsistencies with how browser vendors are dealing with alpha transparency in CSS3 gradients.

Comment: This explanation (transparent is black with 0 alpha) doesn't appear to be accurate. Try a gradient from black to transparent on a black background using 255, 255, 255, 0 as transparent. It'll be very light.

Answer (score 5):

The trick with a color besides white (and with white actually) is to **`rgba` the actual color that is fading**.

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, 
  rgba(111,174,249, 0) 0%,
  rgba(111,174,249, 0) 80%,
  rgb (111,174,249)    100%);
```

*In case the color being used is hex (like `#6faef9`) use [a hex to rgba converter](https://www.rgbtohex.net/hextorgb/) to convert the color.*

Answer (score 3):

The same problem is encountered on native IOS as well:

1. [iOS White to Transparent Gradient Layer is Gray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24882361/ios-white-to-transparent-gradient)
2. https://betterprogramming.pub/the-proper-way-of-creating-a-transparent-gradient-layer-in-ios-b082daa866b1layer-is-gray

I notice that on CSS the solution is to use white color instead of black and then add 0 transparency

```
rgb(255 255 255/0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've recently encountered the same issue regarding transparency on safari. What worked for me was substituting the css into the compiled safari css.

This didn't work for me

```
 background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(56,56,56,1) 5%, rgba(255,255,255,0.001) 100%)
```

This did work for me

```
background-image: linear-gradient(0deg,#383838 5%, hsla(0, 0%, 20%, 0) 100%)
```