# iOS White to Transparent Gradient Layer is Gray

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, calayer, cagradientlayer

I have a CAGradientLayer inserted to the bottom of this small detail view that pops up at the bottom of the app. As you can see, I've set the colors from white to clear, but there's this strange gray tint that is showing up. Any ideas?

```
    // Set up detail view frame and gradient
    [self.detailView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 568, 320, 55)];

    CAGradientLayer *layer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    layer.frame = self.detailView.bounds;
    layer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor, nil];
    layer.startPoint = CGPointMake(1.0f, 0.7f);
    layer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0f, 0.0f);
    [self.detailView.layer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];
```

Here is the problematic view:

[image: Here is the problematic view]

Comment: What's under the layer?

Comment: The MapView. I can set the layer to use clearColor and clearColor and it will be fully transparent.

Comment: What I'm trying to get at: is the layer under this layer grey?

Comment: No... shouldn't insertSublayer at index 0 put this layer on the deepest layer? And if I don't insert the sublayer, the background of the view is clear as it should be. It's only when I set the gradient that that grey color shows up.

Comment: Have you tried setting it to the self.detailView.layer.mask instead?
(self.detailView.layer.mask = layer;)

Comment: Yes, but this mask makes the UILabels transparent too. How do I avoid that?

Comment: Well you could at least NOT add the UILabel to that layer. That seems not to be the best option though. Have you set the backgroundColor of your detailView to be clearColor as well?

Comment: Yea the background is clear.

Comment: That's very strange. Could you try adding another clearcolor to the gradient between the current two please?

Comment: It looks like this: http://imgur.com/jtCYZLN

Answer (score 203, accepted):

clearColor has a black color channel with an alpha of 0, so I had to use

```
[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0]
```

and it works fine.

Comment: It replaces black shadow with white shadow. Still not transparent

Comment: **Important** - for 2018, consider this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25408833/294884

Comment: @RealNmae If you want to go from a colour to clear use UIColor.startColor and UIColor.startColor.withAlphaComponent(0.0) as your two colors.

Comment: @Conor This is actually the correct answer - thanks, works perfectly regardless of colour

Answer (score 65):

In **Swift** This worked for me,

```
UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0).cgColor
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the .cgColor as shown in the answer!!! I accidentally used UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0) and was scratching my head for an hour wondering why it was still gray.

Answer (score 21):

Worth pointing out that any other colour will work like this... using a combination of the two answers above....

**Objective C**

```
UIColor *colour = [UIColor redColor];
NSArray *colourArray = @[(id)[colour colorWithAlphaComponent:0.0f].CGColor,(id)colour.CGColor]
NSArray *locations = @[@0.2,@0.8];

CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradientLayer.colors = colourArray;
gradientLayer.locations = locations;
gradientLayer.frame = self.frame;

[self.layer addSublayer:gradientLayer];
```

**Swift 3**

```
let colour:UIColor = .red
let colours:[CGColor] = [colour.withAlphaComponent(0.0).cgColor,colour.cgColor]
let locations:[NSNumber] = [0.2,0.8]

let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.colors = colours
gradientLayer.locations = locations
gradientLayer.frame = frame

layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

Answer (score 14):

Swift 3 Syntax,

```
UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0).cgColor
```

Answer (score 5):

The answers above such as:

```
UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0).cgColor
```

and

```
UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.0).cgColor
```

should work in terms of getting a portion of your gradient to be clear (rather than the gray that OP is referring to). However, if you're still seeing a transparent white when you should be seeing a clear color, make sure the `backgroundColor` of the view to which you're applying the gradient is clear as well.

By default, that view's background color will likely be white (or a dark color if the device is in dark mode), so when you apply the gradient, the clear portion of it will be "blocked" by the view's `backgroundColor` itself. Set that to clear and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

As many, I still got a gray colour despite using a clear white.

So I changed my approach and went for a mask rather than a gradient. End result is the same, well, better, since this one works in all situations, not just if you got a suitable background.

I did not try this code with IB, but hopefully it works as well.
Just set `backgroundColor` and you are good to go.

```
@IBDesignable
class FadingView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var startLocation: Double =   0.05 { didSet { updateLocations() }}
    @IBInspectable var endLocation:   Double =   0.95 { didSet { updateLocations() }}
    @IBInspectable var horizontalMode:  Bool =  false { didSet { updatePoints() }}
    @IBInspectable var diagonalMode:    Bool =  false { didSet { updatePoints() }}
    @IBInspectable var invertMode:      Bool =  false { didSet { updateColors() }}

    private let gradientLayerMask = CAGradientLayer()

    private func updatePoints() {
        if horizontalMode {
            gradientLayerMask.startPoint = diagonalMode ? CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0) : CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
            gradientLayerMask.endPoint   = diagonalMode ? CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1) : CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
        } else {
            gradientLayerMask.startPoint = diagonalMode ? CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0) : CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
            gradientLayerMask.endPoint   = diagonalMode ? CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1) : CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
        }
    }

    private func updateLocations() {
        gradientLayerMask.locations = [startLocation as NSNumber, endLocation as NSNumber]
    }

    private func updateSize() {
        gradientLayerMask.frame = bounds
    }

    private func updateColors() {
        gradientLayerMask.colors = invertMode ? [UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor] : [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor]
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        layer.mask = gradientLayerMask
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updatePoints()
        updateLocations()
        updateSize()
        updateColors()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that to handle white/black (or really any color with light/dark appearances) gradients based on light/dark mode in iOS 13 that this approach also works with the new system colors:

```
gradientLayer.colors = [
    UIColor.systemBackground.cgColor,
    UIColor.systemBackground.withAlphaComponent(0).cgColor]
```