# How to add gradient in navigation bar - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, gradient

I have researched a lot on how to add gradient in NavigationBar in iOS, but it doesn't show what I need. I want 2 color gradient with WHITE on TOP and CLEAR on BOTTOM. like this :
[image]

Tried using `CAGradientLayer` and also [CRGradientNavigationBar](https://github.com/chroman/CRGradientNavigationBar),
but everything I have tried always shows White on TOP but when i set bottom color to CLEAR, it shows a weird black translucent color.

How to achieve similar NavigationBar like in the picture above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24882361/ios-white-to-transparent-gradient-layer-is-gray) link. Actually `clearColor` has a black color channel with an alpha of 0, so instead use

`[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0]`

and it will do the job! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create gradient layer and add it as background of navigation bar.

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];

gradient.frame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds;

gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], nil];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[self imageFromLayer:gradient] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

For creating image from layer.

```
(UIImage *)imageFromLayer:(CALayer *)layer
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([layer frame].size);

    [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return outputImage;
}
```

One more thing, there is one library available in github : [CRGradientNavigationBar](https://github.com/chroman/CRGradientNavigationBar) you can also use this library.

Comment: I already did both of these things.. Also used CRGradientNavigationBar, but both of them end up showing the translucent black color instead of CLEAR COLOUR

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a UIView on the top of your screen with the top constrain -70, and add CAGradientLayer inside it with it size. 
then make your navigation bar transparent by adding UIImage()//empty image, to is as a background, this way it will show the UIView with grade CAGradientLayer in background