# Windows and MacOS different displays linear gradient

Tags: html, css, windows, macos

Here is a code with background gradient

```
   background: rgba(0,0,0,0) linear-gradient(rgb(245, 245, 245),rgba(0,0,0,0)) 
   repeat scroll 0 0;
```

Windows displays OK (chrome, ie, firefox)
[image: Windows]

MacOS and iphone displays wrong (safari, chrome)

[image]

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/11829410/1207195

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS3 gradient rendering issues from transparent to white](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829410/css3-gradient-rendering-issues-from-transparent-to-white)

Answer (score 0):

Using hex colors instead of rgb/rgba will fix this problem.